# Why is there a change in the probability in the first pick?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

There is a basket with 5 balls; 3 red and 2 white. If in the first pick, you choose a ball, you add another ball of the same color to the basket along with it (if you pick a red ball, now there will be 4 red and 2 white balls; similarly with the white). Now given that in the second pick, you draw a white ball, what is the probability of getting the red ball in the first pick?

Using the Bayes theorem, the answer would be 1/2. But, say if we didn't have the information for the second pick, the answer would have been 3/5.

**This now is my question: why is there a change in the probabilities when there is new information given?**

Comment: Well, why is that surprising?  knowing that you drew a white the second time is evidence for the fact that you drew it the first time (as that would increase the probability of drawing it the second time).  It isn't proof, of course, just evidence.  And evidence changes our beliefs regarding probability.

Comment: Because if no information is given about the second pick, the second pick also could have been a red ball. So the number of possibilities for the first pick to be red has now increased (i.e. RED-RED has now become an available choice)

Answer (score 0):

when you have picked a white ball at second pick then it is more likely to have picked a with ball at the first time that has increased the probability of picking the with ball in second time.

picking a red ball then white ball
$$3/5 * 2/6=1/5$$
picking a white ball then white ball
$$2/5 * 3/6=1/5$$
picking a red ball then red ball
$$3/5 * 4/6=2/5$$
picking a white ball then red ball
$$2/5 * 3/6=1/5$$
so what happened is one of the first two's and we want the probability of 
picking a red ball at first if we have picked a white one at second time
$$
\frac{pr(red \space then \space white)}{pr(red\space then\space white) + pr(white\space then\space white)} = \frac{1/5}{1/5+1/5}$$